# Magento 2.3 file permission

Tags: permissions, magento2.3.0

How to fix file permission, we don't want every time make command for `sudo chmod -R -v 777 var`

Using `Linux`,`centos7`,`cloud server`.having `3` accounts.
About file permission, sometime getting warning can't inside the website, need to refresh 2~3 times.

```
{"0":"Warning: file_put_contents(\/home\/xxx\/public_html\/var\/cache\/\/mage-tags\/mage---b8e_CONFIG): failed to open stream: Permission denied in
```

Comment: Try this `chown apache . -R` and `chgrp apache . -R`

Comment: This is for root? or cd for user? thank you! @AbhishekPanchal

Comment: This from your magento directory. e.g `/var/www/html/magento23/`

Comment: Sorry,i dont understand. we look like `cd /home/(user_name)/public_html/`. So `cd /home/(user_name)/public_html/` and then `chown apache . -R`? thank you! @AbhishekPanchal

Comment: Yeah that's correct in your case.

Comment: But we have 3 user in cloud server, so we need run 3 times for the `cd/user` ? thank you! @AbhishekPanchal

Comment: Yes, I think that means 3 different directory

Comment: not working for me,Warning still. @AbhishekPanchal

Comment: Anyone know how to give write permission in Windows?